# Vectorize a sum without for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Suppose I have some application `f` takes as an argument a 2D vector `v=[x;y]` and returns an n-dimensional vector `f(v)`.

Now I want to implement some application `g` that takes as an argument a matrix `X` that has m 2D-dimensional columns for example `X = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ]` and that sums the image by `f` of each column. I did a non-vectorized version with a `for` loop but I cannot see how to avoid such a loop since I feel we must treat each column one by one

```
[~,size]=size(X);
img=zeros(n,1);

for i=1:size
    col=X(:,i);
img = img + f(col);

end
```

Any ideas to vectorize this ?

Comment: `sum` already have this feature - you simply have to define the dimension to sum over. However, this specification depend on your function f, which should be similarly vectorised - this we cannot help you with without any more detail on that function.

Comment: `[~,size]=size(X);` don't do this, you've overridden the built-in function `size` with a variable called `size`, which is very bad practise. Use variable names which are different from existing function names

Comment: @NickyMattsson f is a very simple but it is given, I cannot modify and just need to re use it as I did in the non-vectorized code, I'll try to use `sum` instead

Comment: @Wolfie Yes of course, I actually code in my native language so I didn't name my variable "size" but I translated it here so that people understand lol

Comment: It's preferably that you post your _exact_ code, even if variable names are in a different language, as long as the actual syntax is in English and preferably comments etc. Otherwise you might introduce new bugs, like you would have here if you tried to use the `size` function again

Comment: What does `f(X)` do? (i.e. is it vectorized?) Why do you want to remove the loop?

Answer (score 0):

For an images this is a 2D-matrix, you can convert it to a vector without using a loop:

```
ImgVector = Img(:);
f=v(:);
```

Or:

```
ImgVector = reshape(Img, 1, []);
f=reshape(v,1,[]);
```